# <asp.HiddenField> value coming as empty in codebehind even after value is set in javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, gridview

Here's my problem. I have a hidden field whose value I change through a javascript method.
The value of hiddenfield is set whenever a row is selected in a gridview with ctrl key pressed.

This is how value for hidden field is assigned (Javascript Code):

```
var curKey;
function checkKey()
{
    //Check if contrl key is pressed or not.
    if (curKey == 17)
    {                
         document.getElementById('<%= CtrlKeyPressed.ClientID %>').value = 'Y';
    }
}
```

In the code, I have called this javasxcript inside gridview_rowdatabound function which would be like given below :

```
 gridview.Rows[i].Attributes.Add("onclick",ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(grvKanban, "Select$" + i) + ";checkKey()");
```

In the body of .aspx page, code is something like this (if control key is pressed while clicking any row in gridview, the value of curKey will be 17):

```
<body onkeyup = "curKey = null;" onkeydown = "curKey=event.keyCode;">
```

For the hidden field, Code is :

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="CtrlKeyPressed" runat="server"/>
```

Basically I want to know whether Ctrl Key is pressed while selecting the gridview row, which I thought of finding with value of Hidden field. But in code behind, when I try to get the value of CtrlKeyPressed.Value is coming as empty string.

Can anyone please help to solve this issue?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run `checkKey()` before the post back. So change this:

```
gridview.Rows[i].Attributes.Add("onclick",
    ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(grvKanban, "Select$" + i) +
    ";checkKey()");
```

to this:

```
gridview.Rows[i].Attributes.Add("onclick",
    "checkKey();" +
    ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(grvKanban, "Select$" + i));
```